# Conda environment package missing in Jupyter with interactive shell

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, conda

I have installed a package in an environment on my system using the following two commands:

```
>>> conda activate pytorch_p36
>>> conda install tensorboard
```

We can see what an expected output looks like, which is the following:

```
>>> tensorboard --version
TensorFlow installation not found - running with reduced feature set.
2.3.0
```

Now, I  open Jupyter Notebook and specify the pytorch_p36 kernel. All relevant packages are recognized when importing modules. However, I do not see what I expected in interactive shell. For example, the following code in Jupyter Notebook:

```
!tensorboard --version
```

Returns the following unexpected output:

```
/usr/bin/sh: 1: tensorboard: not found
```

Even though I am in the environment kernel, how do I execute in the same environment with interactive shell?

Answer (score 0):

The `!` command runs shell command in the Python environment you installed and run Jupyter. It's different from the kernel you choose for the specific Notebook file. You could run this in your terminal, in the conda env you installed tensorboard:

```shell
$ which python
```

And compare with the output of this Jupyter Notebook code:

```
!which python
```

They should be different. So try use `import PACKAGE_NAME` in your Notebook code to see if you have installed the package in the kernel you choose.